# Plone : unbound prefix in configure.zcml

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x, zcml

I am developing a new add-on for my Plone site so as a result it showing my an error in

```
configure.zcml : unbound prefix.
```

Here i am writing my zcml code :

```
    <configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    i18n_domain="customer.reports">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <include package="plone.resource" file="meta.zcml"/>
  <plone:static
      directory="templates"
      type="reports"
      name="customer"
  />
</configure>
```

Unbound prefix error mentioned as below.

> File "/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py", line 38, in
>   fatalError
>           raise exception
>       zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
>           ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml",
>   line 98.4-102.10
>       ZopeSAXParseException: File "/Plone/zinstance/src/customer.reports/customer/reports/configure.zcml",
>   line 13.2,  unbound prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error indicates that you're missing a namespace declaration at the top of your configure.zcml.
Try including one of the following in the configure tag:

```
 xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
```

As i added above line in my code to fix unbound error before this i was using plone to register my add-on but not declare the correct namespace i.e. plone at the name space declaration block of zcml file

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
    i18n_domain="customer.reports">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <!-- -*- extra stuff goes here -*- -->

  <include package="plone.resource" file="meta.zcml"/>
  <plone:static
      directory="templates"
      type="reports"
      name="customer"
  />
</configure>
```

Comment: Right, so please upvote & accept the person who answered your question, rather than basically copying their answer & upvoting yourself.  People who help should be rewarded, don't you think?

Comment: firstly..keep in your mind that i am not copied the answer @Danimal .... i wrote my complete summarized answer... u edited that above answer...before it was not understandable.

Comment: Ok, sorry - my mistake, but seeing @Alexander added his answer first made me jump to that conclusion.  In any case - his answer is essentially correct, it just needed clarifying.

Comment: Hi @BhartiRawat, indeed it would be nice to merge both answers into one, also for better readability. Can you see an edit button at Alexander Kogtenkov's answer to extend it?

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not define a prefix `plone` that you are using in the element `plone:static`. You may need to add the corresponding namespace declaration somewhere, e.g. in the `configure` element: `xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"`.